# Error Deploying Next app to vercel (ReferenceError: location is not defined)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, location, router, vercel

I have been trying to deploy a project developed using Next.js on vercel from my gitHub, but i have been encountering error saying `ReferenceError: location is not defined`
[image]
I have checked for solutions online.
Some says in due to `import { useRouter } from "next/client";`  instate i should use `import { useRouter } from "next/router";` but in my project am using `import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";`.
According to this [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/11fuwys/nextjs_13_referenceerror_location_is_not_defined/)
that `useRouter` is client-side, the server has no knowledge of it. That this problem can be solved by wrapping automatic routing logic inside a useEffect, which will only run once the component is loaded on the frontend. The issue am having now is how will I implement that because I have this hook in quiet much places in my project. For example:
**This is one the component:**

```
const LoginPage = () => {
  const { authStatus } = useSelector((store: any) => store.shop);
  const router = useRouter();
  if (authStatus) {
    router.replace("/");
    return (
      <>
        <div className="w-full h-screen flex justify-center items-center">
          <Lottie className="w-[10rem] h-[10rem]" animationData={lottieLoad} loop={true} />
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Login />
    </>
  );
};

export default LoginPage;
```

**This is another one:**

```
const WishlistBtn = ({ product }: Props) => {
  const { user, authStatus } = useSelector((store: any) => store.shop);
  const router = useRouter();
  const handleAddWishlist = async () => {
    if (!authStatus) {
      router.replace("/login");
    } else {
      try {
        const existProduct = await appwriteServices.isProductInCart({
          productId: product?._id,
          userId: user?.$id,
        });
        if (existProduct) {
        }
        await appwriteServices.createWishlist({
          userId: user.$id,
          productName: product?.name,
          maxPrice: product?.maxPrice,
          minPrice: product?.minPrice,
          imageURL: product?.image?.asset._ref,
          stylist: product?.stylist,
          productId: product?._id,
          uniqueId: "",
        });
      } catch (error) {}
    }
  };
```

**And this too:**
export default function AddCartButton({ product }: Props) {
const router = useRouter();

const { user, authStatus } = useSelector((store: any) => store.shop);

```
const handleAddToCart = async () => {
    if (!authStatus) {
      router.replace("/login");
    } else {
      // check if product already in the cart. If in cart, increase quantity
      const productInCart = await appwriteServices.isProductInCart({
        productId: product._id,
        userId: user?.$id,
      });

      if (productInCart) {
        return (
          <>
            <Message text="Sorry, item is already in the cart" redirectRoute="/products" />
          </>
        );
      } else {
        await appwriteServices.addToCart({
          userId: user?.$id,
          imageURL: product?.image.asset._ref,
          productName: product?.name,
          minPrice: product?.minPrice,
          maxPrice: product?.maxPrice,
          stylist: product?.stylist,
          productId: product?._id,
          quantity: 1,
        });
      }
      // if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      //   window.location.reload();
      // }
      router.push("/cart");
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Next.JS seems to struggle with useRouter even if you use the `'use client'`.

My workaround is to use `useEffect()`. So replace

```
if (!authStatus) router.replace("/login");
```

with

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!authStatus) router.replace("/login");
}, [authStatus])
```